# Why getting error while creating internal table based on hbase table in Hive?

Tags: hive, hbase

I have a hbase table which I want to map it to a hive table. The problem is while I use external table in hive it will be done but when I want to create internal table in hive it throws an exception :

```
message:Table yourtable *already exists within HBase*; use CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE instead to register it in Hive
```

Command used :

```
CREATE TABLE A
(key string, date_time timestamp)   
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'   
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "hbase.columns.mapping" = "
               :key,
               :timestamp
                )
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "yourtable");
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is you hive version?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. Unfortunetly it did not work.I am trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a version of Hive which doesn't support a tag you may be using.

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] [EXTERNAL] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name    -- (Note: TEMPORARY available in Hive 0.14.0 and later)
  [(col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)]
  [COMMENT table_comment]
  [PARTITIONED BY (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)]
  [CLUSTERED BY (col_name, col_name, ...) [SORTED BY (col_name [ASC|DESC], ...)] INTO num_buckets BUCKETS]
  [SKEWED BY (col_name, col_name, ...)                  -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.10.0 and later)]
     ON ((col_value, col_value, ...), (col_value, col_value, ...), ...)
     [STORED AS DIRECTORIES]
  [
   [ROW FORMAT row_format] 
   [STORED AS file_format]
     | STORED BY 'storage.handler.class.name' [WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (...)]  -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.6.0 and later)
  ]
  [LOCATION hdfs_path]
  [TBLPROPERTIES (property_name=property_value, ...)]   -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.6.0 and later)
  [AS select_statement];   -- (Note: Available in Hive 0.5.0 and later; not supported for external tables)
```

Refer: [Create Table syntax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable)

Answer (score 0):

Hive and HBase both use the same metastore to store table meta data. The problem you are having is that while creating a new Hive managed (internal) table *to point to HBase table*, the metastore is refusing to create a new HBase table with the same name because the HBase table already exists. Using `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`, you can let metastore know to only register a new hive external table while keeping the same existing HBase table.